# How to generate multiple plots using modules?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create multiple plots using modules, each plot with it's own input. But when I tried to run the app, only the inputs are added each time I add using insertUI and the plot output is blank.

I've tried connecting the ui and the server modules with the same id ("hist1") but it doesn't seem to connect each individual module.

```
histogramUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars)),
    numericInput(NS(id, "bins"), "bins", value = 10, min = 1),
    plotOutput(NS(id, "hist"))
  )
}


histogramServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var]])
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(data(), breaks = input$bins, main = input$var)
    }, res = 96)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add"),
  div(id = "add_here")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  histogramServer("hist1")
  
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = histogramUI("hist1"))
  })
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]

Comment: right now you only create one `histogramServer` and all the `histrogramUI`s have the same `id`. Is this what you want? Usually, with every `add` you create a new set of `histogramServer`/`histogramUI` that share an `id` (but a different one from before)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to get a new set of histogramServer/histogramUI with unique ids. But I didn't know that the current app didn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution where every time you click `add` you generate a new pair of `histogramServer`/`histogramUI` which have the same `id` (but a different one than the one before, because `add` gets incremented):

```
library(shiny)

histogramUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars)),
    numericInput(NS(id, "bins"), "bins", value = 10, min = 1),
    plotOutput(NS(id, "hist"))
  )
}


histogramServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var]])
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(data(), breaks = input$bins, main = input$var)
    }, res = 96)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add"),
  div(id = "add_here")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    histogramServer(paste0("hist_", input$add))
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", ui = histogramUI(paste0("hist_", input$add)))
  })
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Beautiful! I have a follow up question built on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67973185/how-to-bookmark-and-restore-app-with-insertui-modules